# skip re-render using shouldComponentUpdate and nextState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, rerender

I have currently a drop-down `select` to filter some charts after 'Apply'. It works fine.(See screenshot below).
[image]

The problem is that when another timespan gets selected, React does a re-render to all charts before I click 'Apply' button.

I want to avoid this unnecessary re-render by implementing`shouldComponentUpdate`, but I can't figure out how.

Below what I tried but it did not work(still a re-render):

```html
shouldComponentUpdate(nextState) {
        if (this.state.timespanState !== nextState.timespanState) {
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
```

But it always return `true`, because `nextState.timespanState` is `undefined`. Why?

Drop-down Select

```html
<Select value={this.state.timespanState} onChange={this.handleTimeSpanChange}>
```

```html
handleTimeSpanChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ timespanState: event.target.value });
    };
```

```html
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { timespanState: 'Today'};
        this.handleTimeSpanChange = this.handleTimeSpanChange.bind(this);
    }
```

Comment: `want to avoid this unnecessary re-render` Why do you want to do this? Are you seeing performance issues?  Are you seeing logical errors?

Comment: @Adam because this is a unnecessary re-render, I want to the charts get updated after I click the 'apply' button

Comment: From a UX perspective, you should probably just get rid of the apply button if all it does is re-render the charts, you're making the user click again for no reason. Secondly, rather than `shouldComponentUpdate`, which is a bug trap, you should only be passing the "applied" value. This can be done by adding a second state field `appliedTimeSpan` and updating it when the user clicks the apply button and passing `appliedTimeSpan` to the chart components. **Using `shouldComponentUpdate` to control renders is bad practice (from my perspective) because of the high possibility of bugs.**

Comment: @Adam I also realize that shouldComponentUpdate is not a good solution in my case. Because on the one hand I don't want to re-render charts, on the other hands I want to re-render timespan drop-down when it change. Therefore, it's difficult to controle

Comment: Can you post more component code, it certainly sounds like the second state field of `appliedTimeSpan` would fix your issue.

Comment: "From a UX perspective, you should probably just get rid of the apply button if all it does is re-render the charts, you're making the user click again for no reason" your statement is not very true. The current situation is like: When an another timespan in drop-down gets selected, it does a re-render with the exact same charts without api-calls, but when users click apply button, charts get re-rendered with api-calls to fetch new data

Comment: I don't see any benefit to use the second state field of appliedTimeSpan. We use states to easily controle changes. Thus, a timeSpanState can hold all behaviors. (in my opinion)

Comment: Haha, fine by me, you're the one asking the question "how do I fix this". If you've already arrived at the conclusion that you should be using `shouldComponentUpdate` (hint: you shouldn't) then you've got yourself an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with using `shouldComponentUpdate`, it's just that the first parameter is `nextProps` and the second is `nextState`, so in your case, the `undefined` value is actually `nextProps` with the wrong name.

Change your code to this,

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState) { // <-- tweak this line
        if (this.state.timespanState !== nextState.timespanState) {
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works, but now still a little problem: the drop-down does not display the selected item (cause it returns a false and thus no re-render), it keeps displaying 'Today' while timespanState is already changed to 'Yesterday' in debugging for example

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve the problem by separating drop-down selectbox and charts into two apart components and made the drop-down component as a child component from its parent component, charts components.
The reason is the following statement

> React components automatically re-render whenever there is a change in their state or props.

Therefore, React will re-render everything in render() method of this component. So keeping them in two separate components will let them re-render without side effect. In my case, any state changes in drop-down or other states in Filter component, will only cause a re-render inside this component. Then passing the updated states to charts component with a callback function.

Something like below:

Child component

```js
export class Filter extends Component {

  handleApplyChanges = () => {
    this.props.renderPieChart(data);
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      ...
      <Button onClick={this.handleApplyChanges} />
    );
  }
}
```

Parent component

```js
export class Charts extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        this.state = { dataForPieChart: []};
        this.renderPieChart = this.renderPieChart.bind(this);
      }
      
      renderPieChart = (data) => {
            this.setState({ dataForPieChart: data });
      }
      
      render(){
        return (
          <Filter renderPieChart={this.renderPieChart} />
          <Chart>
            ...data={this.state.dataForPieChart}
          </Chart>
        );
      }
    }
```

If still any question, disagreement or suggestions, pls let me know:)